# Vaccum container and dispenser?

Tags: storage

Is there a vacuum container that can dispense coffee without letting air in so I don't have to vacuum it everytime I need to make coffee?

P.S., English is not my first language. Feel free to rephrase the question and correct grammar/spelling mistakes.

Comment: How can you dispense anything without letting air in? Are you wanting just an air tight container or something that somehow can be vacuum air tight? This question feels off topic as product recommendations are off topic here

Comment: @EdChum The user is asking if such a "solution" exists... which is not really the same thing as soliciting opinions about which brand of something to buy. Such questions are perfectly appropriate for Q&A (although I don't think we are going to find a solution here).  But asking if a solution exists (even if it is a product) is ***not*** what was ever meant by a "product recommendation."

Comment: @EdChum - Dispensing something from a container without letting anything in CAN be done, it's just very complex. It would take two independently vacuumed chambers. I highly doubt there is any product like this.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I didn't flag or vote to close this unlike other questions as the OP's native language is not English so I sought a little clarification, you're correct that it's not asking for a product recommendation, I've never seen such a device though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe such a product exists at a consumer level for dispensing coffee.

Hypothetically, you would need a vacuum-sealed container that also incorporates some sort of outlet corridor where the coffee could enter, which would then need to be sealed from the inside before dispensing the coffee. It would be like an "air lock" in a miniature coffee spacecraft.

But if this is simply a labor-saving effort, **there *are* touchless, automatic vacuum-sealed containers** that re-establish the vacuum every time you close it (search https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=automatic+vacuum+container).

But on a broader note, if you find reestablishing the vacuum each time a bit more trouble than you would like, you might **consider removing a few-days supply at a time,** and just storing what you need in a regular air-tight container for your short-term daily use. Vacuum-sealing is optimal for longer-term storage, but I don't think you will find a *perceptible* loss of quality over a few days if you keep enough for your immediate needs in a regular air-tight container.

Comment: Thanks. Automatic vacuum-sealed containers are good enough for me. As a programmer, I'm used to not rely on the user to maintain a valid state for the system. The container is shared by several people and  I want to make sure it will remain vacuum-sealed without altering their behavior (open the container, take some coffee, close it again).  

P.S., I'm unable to upvote you because I don't have enough reputation points.